# Регулярные выражения. Парсинг JSON

Tags: регулярные-выражения, json

```
|\{(.*)("need": true)(.*)\}|s
```

Как правильно написать регулярное выражение что бы из JSON коллекции можно было вытянуть определенный объект?

Пример:

```
[
  {
    "object": 1,
    "need": true,
    "items": [
      {
        "subobject": 1
      },
      {
        "subobject": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "object": 2,
    "items": [
      {
        "subobject": 3
      },
      {
        "subobject": 4,
        "need": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Задача: Как вытащить вложенный объект с свойством "need": true ?

Я бы с удовольствием использовал готовую библиотеку, но моя задача не так касается JSON как фигурных скобок которые вложены друг в друга, а JSON я привёл чисто для примера.

Comment: не надо парсить json регулярными выражениями

Comment: @diraria это прямо в ответ надо, чтобы ссылку на этот вопрос давать каждый раз, когда захотят использовать не готовые библиотеки для JSON

Comment: я бы с удовольствием этого не делал, но это не так JSON связано как с самой сложностью поиска вложенных объектов которые обернуты в повторяющиеся фигурные скобки

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы в нем была ваша задача. Потому что пока лучшим ответом на ваш вопрос по прежнему будет "не надо парсить Json регулярками"

Answer (score 6):

Привет

*"Не надо парсить JSON регулярками..."*

Да не надо, структура может быть разная у одного и того-же файла.

В зависимости от области применения используйте соответствующие инструменты или библиотеки.

Полный список на оф. сайте

https://www.json.org/

Некоторые, из самых востребуемых:

**Unix shell**

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

**Python**

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

**Ruby**

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html

**C++**

https://github.com/nlohmann/json

**Common Lisp**

https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-json/

**Rust**

https://github.com/serde-rs/json

**Java**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

**Go**

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

**Perl**

http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/JSON-2.97000/lib/JSON.pm

---

**Пример jq**

```
~$ echo "[ { "object": 1, "need": true, "items": [ { "subobject": 1 }, { "subobject": 2 } ] }, { "object": 2, "items": [ { "subobject": 3 }, { "subobject": 4, "need": true } ] } ]" | jq '.[1].[1].need'
```

В документации **jq** ознакомтесь с фильтром select() думаю то, что вам нужно.